# doxygen listing 2 method for every java method

Tags: java, doxygen

I'm using doxygen 1.7.1 mac gui front end.

The generation of the documentation is fine except for every method in my classes it outputs 2 methods with the same signature. One is commented and the other is blank. If I take out the comments, I still get 2 methods with the same signature.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried it again the next day, and I didn't have any problems with double functions. I'm not sure why I was having so much trouble.